# What Input Image Size is Correct for the Version of ResNet V2 in TensorFlow-Slim

Tags: tensorflow

There is some ambiguity in the documentation of ResNet V2 in the TesnorFlow-Slim that I can't quite sort out.

In the [README.md](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/README.md), they say to use a 299x299 input image:

> ^ ResNet V2 models use Inception pre-processing and input image size of 299 (use --preprocessing_name inception --eval_image_size 299
>   when using eval_image_classifier.py).

But then, in the comments [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/nets/resnet_v2.py#L37), they are using an image of 224x224:

```
   # inputs has shape [batch, 224, 224, 3]
   with slim.arg_scope(resnet_v2.resnet_arg_scope()):
      net, end_points = resnet_v2.resnet_v2_101(inputs, 1000, is_training=False)
```

The paper that introduced ResNet V2, is a bit confusing on this point.  They provide a table, but I'm unclear as to whether the "train crop" (224x224), or the "test crop" (320x320) is the inference image size.

The model graph, itself, offers no help; it appears to be equally valid with either input image size, on account of how the convolutions and pooling are positioned.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**
I have run a small number of experiments, and seem to get better classification results with a 224x224 input image.

Comment: I believe the test crop is the inference image size.

Comment: From that line, it seems that the comment is referring to another architecture instead. Personally, I find the 299 size is catered towards the imagenet prediction, and I would try whatever size that works the best for my task at hand. There is probably no one ideal size for any network - it depends on the task.

Answer (score 3):

so the official site says input size for

1. VGG16, VGG19, and ResNet  :224*224
2. Xception:299*299